# Service Stack plugins not killing application after failure

Tags: servicestack

It seems as though service stack is swallowing exceptions thrown by custom plugins. The only way I can determine that a plugin has failed is with exception breaker.

Is there a way to throw an exception in a plugin to kill the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions thrown by plugins are stored in `AppHost.StartUpErrors` which can be viewed by going to [?debug=requestinfo in DebugMode](http://docs.servicestack.net/debugging#request-info).

You can bubble a Plugin Exception by registering an AfterInitCallback and checking for any Startup Errors, e.g:

```
AfterInitCallbacks.Add(host => {
    var appHost = (ServiceStackHost)host;
    if (appHost.StartUpErrors.Count > 0)
        throw new Exception(appHost.StartUpErrors[0].Message);
});
```